# Fix up path of all includes in C++ files in subdirectories

Tags: c++

I have some unix source I'm trying to get to work in VS. All the #includes are coded, I guess, for some user defined header path. e.g., `#include <myheader>`, but myheader exists in the projects folder like `..\headers\myheader.hpp`.

Is there any utility that will scan all the C++ files recursively and fix up the #include's with headers found in those subdirectories?

e.g., it would convert

```
#include <myheader>
```

to

```
#include "..\headers\myheader.hpp"
```

?

(else I have to flatten the hierarchy because it's a bit of a mess)

(there is no need to worry about potential duplicate headers...)

Comment: Why not just add headers path to the compiler?

Comment: You really shouldn't include directory paths as part of your #includes - it makes the code base messy, fragile and hard to maintain. The correct solution is to specify search paths for your compiler to help it find the required #includes.

Comment: @x13n Because that is hard coding the paths... there is no reason to do that. The code writers should have used relative paths in the first place. (Also, there are about 50 dirs and each one would need to be included... just waste to do it that way instead of the right way in the first place)

Comment: @PaulR It's called relative paths.

Comment: @AD: it's nothing to do with relative or absolute paths - it's just good engineering practice to keep the paths out of the source files and in a makefile or project file where they belong.

Comment: @PaulR That maybe true BUT this project has 50 directories that mix and match the includes from different directories and I'm not going to try to mess wiht it. I could get the list of directories, and concatenate them and put them in the project file but then if thats the way to do it, there should be a setting to tell the compiler just to use all the subdirectories as includes(as that is what I'm doing). Relative paths are the best way as there is no ambiguity in the process. Also, many people use relative paths... it's not the same as absolute paths.

Comment: If you keep the list of include directories in a makefile then it only needs to be done once and then it can be maintained in just one place (SPOT principle). Your source code then does not need to be polluted with unnecessary details which could later change and require multiple modifications. But hey if you like scattering all this information throughout your code then go right ahead...

Comment: @AbstractDissonance, do I understand it right that you want a "utility" that finds `#include` directive, *finds* corresponding headers in the whole tree and replaces them? How was this code compiled before? I take it you're working off of some established codebase?

Comment: Lets be clear, this is not my source code! I don't program in C/C++ precisely because of this type of mess!

Comment: @AbstractDissonance, you have really strong opinions that are based on the lack of knowledge. And, I think you can work a bit on being nicer to the people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend that you add your `headers` directory to the include path somewhere in project options instead.

Comment: I'm not going to include 50 paths when all that needs to be done is the files need to use relative paths for the includes. I guess I'll have to make my own utility

Comment: You scattered your headers over 50 directories? You should consider amending your layout. It is more common (and you even see now why) to keep includes files in one directory and sources in the other (one or more).

Comment: It might have not been clear but by "unix" sources on VS I meant it was something I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding directory paths to headers, I agree with the other posters.

In case you need to replace a certain pattern recursively in files, then you should learn how to use `find` and `sed`for this (in case you are on a Unixoid OS).

The solution in your case would look like

```
find . -name \*.cpp -exec sed -i -e 's/old/new/g' {} \;
```

I bet you will need to make use of this at some point in your life 8^)

Comment: Although it's a good idea to actually answer the question, I take it `VS` isn't running on unices. Of course, there's a cygwin, but…

Comment: Hmm, I'm familiar with find but never heard of sed. I'll look it up but it's generally easier to write a small utility than use these terse command line utilities that can easily ruin files if you get something wrong. In any case, I don't see how to use find or sed to find the relative paths of the header files? (you gotta do a search for them)